# How to verify a PGP-signed text with BouncyCastle in Java without a public-key

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pgp

I've studied a lot of examples and do a lot of research but I could not figure how to verify a signed text (PGP) without having a public-key.

I just want to ensure that the text has not been changed after creation.

Any hints are welcome!

Example:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

Beispiel text

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: BCPG v1.59

iQEcBAEBAgAGBQJbbYOlAAoJEOvsgYjY/KHJUrkH/RDoFkONolpEEjafqjk3NOlg
uELyCF0vE/msFD2SO5O98HD4egnpxlO+fyJiZ2x+c0B52KQuOztAOYTHly2NKrL7
65gEIzOmpu+yQhYlZr4Qp2xGStJqxfgMeAIv3UUjUoRE7DWMZwgpO1KqGUhB05TL
XXyzWLJND27SzpNjpRmUmf+uuLKZHQ55q1dapwZym2Xg5il+UzYuJjfle9jvBWtc
uPJ40ghE/ms8WjAUAEOsdPB3rFd65pjwcauClM05L7w7KIv3/hgoAI/zZyGWW40B
yQuTbt2nYeZO4NbXkosiq9db4Lo5tEPdUH1NI3e34e2gymhCFOOguT3dAoafYYw=
=JrA1
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

Comment: Without the public-key, wouldn't it be close to impossible to verify that the PGP signed message is valid and/or unchanged?

Comment: Although, saying that, the SHA1/MD5 hash of the entire message should be able to verify that the message hasn't been changed since creation, but that's only if you are 100% sure you have access to the message first to generate said hash with.

Comment: I thought even the hash value was encrypted with the sender's private key, so without the matching public key, there'd be no way to even read the hash...

Comment: @IsThisJavascript I don't think so, that is exactly what email programs are doing.  And that's the sense of signing mails I guess!?

Comment: @ThiloSchwarz No idea. To be honest, I don't mess around with emails that much. However I am curious about this topic

Comment: What do you mean by "has not been changed after creation"? Signatures are first hashed with certain algorithm (SHA1) then encrypted by the private-key, only public-key can decrypt.

Comment: @zhh not quite. Only the private key can decrypt. The public key is used for verifying a message or encrypting a message that is only viewable by the person holding the private key

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Signature needs to be verifiable by those who have public key, so it must be encrypted by the private key.

Comment: Ahh I see. For digital signatures it's the reverse. Sorry :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all!

I was wrong! A public-key is needed for decryption **and** verification!

Have a look at the output of gpg, it is the *de facto* standard:

```
cat |gpg --verify
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

Beispiel text

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: BCPG v1.59

iQEcBAEBAgAGBQJbbYOlAAoJEOvsgYjY/KHJUrkH/RDoFkONolpEEjafqjk3NOlg
uELyCF0vE/msFD2SO5O98HD4egnpxlO+fyJiZ2x+c0B52KQuOztAOYTHly2NKrL7
65gEIzOmpu+yQhYlZr4Qp2xGStJqxfgMeAIv3UUjUoRE7DWMZwgpO1KqGUhB05TL
XXyzWLJND27SzpNjpRmUmf+uuLKZHQ55q1dapwZym2Xg5il+UzYuJjfle9jvBWtc
uPJ40ghE/ms8WjAUAEOsdPB3rFd65pjwcauClM05L7w7KIv3/hgoAI/zZyGWW40B
yQuTbt2nYeZO4NbXkosiq9db4Lo5tEPdUH1NI3e34e2gymhCFOOguT3dAoafYYw=
=JrA1
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
gpg: Signature made Fri Aug 10 14:23:01 2018 CEST
gpg:                using RSA key EBEC8188D8FCA1C9
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Comment: What? Look at the last line: `Can't check signature: No public key`